# Como identificar classes em um sistema orientado a objetos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software

Ao trabalharmos com orientação a objetos é preciso saber identificar quais classes são necessárias para uma certa aplicação. Algumas classes costumam ser "óbvias" em certo sentido: em um sistema de gerenciamento de produtos é intuitivamente claro que vamos precisar de classes `Produto`, `Fornecedor`, etc.

Inclusive, para "detectar" essas classes mais "óbvias" até ouvi falar de uma técnica: escrever casos de uso e então olhar os substantivos nesses casos de uso. Depois disso então filtramos essa lista de substantivos que obtemos pra ver quais realmente devem ser classes, ou seja, quais realmente representam conceitos importantes do problema tratado.

Mas existem classes que não são tão obvias e que eu acredito que não apareçam nos casos de uso. Por exemplo, considerando ASP.NET WebAPI, ao criarmos o projeto padrão no VS 2013 temos a classe `ApplicationOAuthProvider`, a classe `ChallengeResult` e além disso temos de criar os controllers.

Isso que falei é só um exemplo, porque realmente não sei uma forma melhor de expressar isso. O fato principal é que essas classes todas *não* me parecem óbvias, e me parece muito pouco provavel que elas apareçam nos casos de uso.

Dessa forma, como podemos identificar as classes necessárias em um sistema orientado a objetos? Além da técnica de analisar os casos de uso, como podemos achar essas classes "menos óbvias"? Eu sei que esse assunto é *muito* extenso, por isso se possível peço referências para estudar mais sobre isso.

Comment: Não vou responder porque uma resposta é muito difícil. O problema ocorre porque o mercado acha que o programador deve entender de todos os domínios possíveis cuja lei não exija um profissional próprio certificado de alguma forma. A maioria dos programadores não entendem tanto de regras de negócios quando as empresas gostariam, aí a organização de um sistema, as tais classes óbvias, acabam não ficando tão óbvias assim. O programador faz muita coisa sem pensar corretamente. E nos casos de envolver tecnologia diretamente? Ninguém é especialista em tudo.

Comment: A maioria não entende de segurança, de concorrência, de uma API específica. Até aprender usar coisas prontas para essas coisas faz parte da obrigação do programador. Mas só um especialista vai entender do assunto com a profundidade que é necessária. Mais ainda. Ele não vai dominar sozinho, ele precisa de uma equipe extensa, precisa ter outras pessoas para consultar. Resumindo: um programador especialista no assunto tem uma chance grande de escolher a forma correta de criação dessas classes, mas ainda assim pode errar. Imagine o que não é especialista no assunto que ele está criando a classe.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## TL;DR

Não misture a Análise do problema com o Design (projeto) da solução, nem com a Implementação tecnológica.

## Análise

Um analista é o profissional responsável por identificar um problema a ser resolvido ou necessidade a ser atendida e elicitar os requisitos para a criação de uma solução.

O conjunto de requisitos define o que o sistema deve fazer para atender às necessidades identificadas.

Baseando-se nos requisitos, o analista continua o processo de Análise identificando em alto nível de quais funcionalidades o sistema deverá possuir para atender aos requisitos.

Uma solução comum para mapear cada funcionalidade é através de Casos de Uso (não confundir com o Diagrama de Caso de Uso da UML). Um caso de uso é em geral uma espécie de passo-a-passo da interação entre usuário e sistema, embora esse conceito possa variar. Além disso, geralmente ele descreve as pré-condições necessárias para a correta execução daquele caso de uso e as pós-condições, que são os resultados da ação realizada.

Note que ainda estamos em alto nível e nada aqui tem a ver com a solução tecnológica envolvida.

Continuando, se o analista é treinado em orientação a objetos e UML, ele pode optar por modelar esse conhecimento do domínio e do problema utilizando os diagramas adequados, que geralmente são: Diagrama de Caso de Uso, Diagrama de Atividades, Diagrama de Classes e Diagrama de Estados.

O **Diagrama de Caso de Uso** é uma representação visual simples das interações do sistema com o mundo externo. Os atores que interagem com o sistema são representações de usuários, outros sistemas ou qualquer entidade externa ao sistema que se comunique com o mesmo. Este diagrama não exclui a necessidade de mapear os casos de uso conforme descrito anteriormente.

O **Diagrama de Atividades** representa os passos do caso de uso numa espécie de fluxograma, incluindo bifurcações com cenários alternativos, cenários de erro, etc. Nem todos os cenários precisam ser representados no mesmo diagrama.

O **Diagrama de Classes**, neste estágio de um projeto, **deve incluir apenas as classes de domínio**, não incluindo classes específicas de frameworks, bibliotecas, nem qualquer referência à tecnologia que será usada para implementação. Poderíamos chamar este diagrama de **Diagrama de Classes de Domínio**. A função do diagrama é representar as entidades necessárias e o relacionamento entre elas. Em suma, é a forma moderna e orientada a objetos do Diagrama de Entidade-Relacionamento (DER), embora ambos possam ser usados. O DER geralmente é associado à modelagem estruturada.

O **Diagrama de Estados** é usado para as entidades do sistema que seguem um fluxo de estados. Por exemplo, uma parcela pode estar "em aberto", "liquidada", "em atraso", "em prejuízo". Este diagrama representa os estados e como ocorrem as transições entre eles.

Através de tudo isso, o analista pode validar a solução, não considerando a parte tecnológica, mas verificando se as classes e os casos de uso atendem aos requisitos. Por exemplo, se houver um requisito de que "o gerente poderá extrair um relatório com o total de produtos vendidos no mês", então o analista deve olhar se a classe `Produto` possui um relacionamento "navegável" com `Venda` e `ItemVenda`. Ele também pode adicionar às classes alguns métodos e atributos mais importantes para atender a esses requisitos.

## Design

Com base em todas essas informações, entram em ação os arquitetos e desenvolvedores para propor uma solução tecnológica para o problema. Isso não necessariamente vem em sequência, mas muito pode ocorrer em paralelo.

Os projetistas técnicos poderão criar vários outros diagramas para representar o que será implementado, mas dificilmente chegarão ao nível de detalhe de colocar classes de um framework.

Os diagramas mais relevantes e geralmente usados são:

- **Diagrama de Componentes**: representa a divisão em alto nível dos componentes principais do sistema. A divisão não representa a estrutura de pastas dos arquivos do projetos, mas é uma divisão lógica de responsabilidades.
- **Diagrama de Deployment**: uma representação do ambiente onde o sistema será executado.
- **Diagrama de Sequência**: para uma determinada ação no sistema, este diagrama representa a interação entre diversos objetos através das chamadas executadas e do retorno, permitindo visualizar a sequência de chamadas a métodos no tempo.

O design também pode ser feito de forma agnóstica, isto é, sem considerar quais tecnologias, frameworks e bibliotecas serão usadas. No entanto, creio que é mais produtivo modelar a divisão de componentes e classes já pensando na implementação, de forma a não gerar mais um *gap* de informação.

Note que cada um dos diagramas citados podem ser feitos para vários casos diferentes. Quando falamos em Diagrama de Classes ou Diagrama de Componentes, não falamos de um único diagrama que representa o sistema como um todo. A representação pode ser feita em **níveis diferentes**, por exemplo, um mostrando os componentes gerais do sistema e outros diagramas mostrando a estrutura interna de cada componente individualmente. A representação também pode ser feita em **contextos diferentes**, por exemplo, podem ser feitos vários diagramas para representar apenas o necessário para uma funcionalidade importante, ignorando classes e pacotes não relevantes nesse contexto.

## Implementação

A implementação deve seguir o que foi definido no design, porém, isso não significa que cada método, classe, pacote e componente deve ser mapeado um-para-um no projeto "físico", seus arquivos e estrutura de diretórios.

O programador deve ter a liberdade de encontrar a melhor solução para atender ao que foi solicitado com a estrutura que ele desejar. Seria péssimo do ponto de vista de boas práticas, impor cada detalhe do que deve ser implementado. Se isso fosse possível, não precisaríamos de programadores, mas de um gerador de código.

## Construindo a ponte

Ao estudar com atenção as "fases" (entre aspas porque não são uma sequência linear) de um projeto de desenvolvimento de software, é possível notar que existe um grande salto (*gap*). Uma analogia comumente usada nos livros de Engenharia de Software consiste em construir uma ponte entre o que o cliente precisa e a solução tecnológica.

Ainda hoje, a Engenharia de Software é uma disciplina um tanto imatura, não temos uma forma padronizada como a Civil ou Elétrica para trabalhar. A validade de um Modelo de Análise, um Modelo de Design ou da solução implementada depende quase exclusivamente de fatores humanos, como a capacidade de comunicação e entendimento dos analistas.

Não existe uma regra formal para representar a modelagem de dados. A UML foi um grande avanço, mas os diversos diagramas em geral variam em nível de detalhe, abrangência e muitos outros fatores de projeto para projeto, de equipe para equipe e de indivíduo para indivíduo.

## Considerações finais

Mesmo com as últimas afirmações acima, não quero ser pessimista. Embora não haja uma resposta definitiva para a modelagem de sistemas, existem alguns princípios que podem nos guiar:

- **Coloque a comunicação em primeiro lugar**. O objetivo de um diagrama é comunicar informação e não simplesmente ser um espelho do código. Se um diagrama não comunica algo útil, não perca tempo com ele. Considere sua equipe e o seu projeto e faça os diagramas que forem relevantes com os detalhes relevantes para que as pessoas saibam o que estão fazendo. O seu time consegue se reunir numa mesa e discutir um diagrama, rabiscando-o e usando-o como base para a conversa?
- **Não faça diagramas de tecnologias específicas**. Se alguém quiser saber como Servlets, Rails ou Django funcionam, é melhor comprar um livro. Você só vai confundir as pessoas. Já vi muitos diagramas por aí que nada mais são do que o modelo MVC com nomes diferentes.
- **Verifique se o diagrama atende os requisitos**. O seu diagrama deve ser útil não só para entender o que deve ser feito, mas também para validar se a sua solução atende ao que o cliente precisa. Faça testes mentais lógicos, olhando para as classes, métodos e relacionamentos, verificando se elas tem motivo de estarem ali, se para um certo cenários você consegue extrair os dados necessários, etc.

Como mencionei algumas vezes, a Análise, o Design e a implementação provavelmente serão feitas muitas vezes durante o ciclo de desenvolvimento. Não espere ter tudo certo no começo. Investir tempo demais em detalhamento é ruim, segundo vários autores.

Esse método de identificar classes através de substantivos pode ser útil quando você não tem ideia do que está fazendo, mas é péssima porque trata-se de uma tentativa de criar uma forma "burra" de extrair informação, sem análise crítica.

Aliás, a palavra "extrair" é muitas vezes usada indevidamente. Quando criamos um sistema, não *extraímos* os requisitos e as classes necessárias como se elas já existissem ali, ocultas de alguma forma. Quanto às classes, nós simplesmente definimos de forma espúria quais classes um sistema terá de modo a atender às necessidades. Trata-se de um processo criativo e não de um processo de extração como se faz com matéria prima. Por "criativa", não pense em arte pós-moderna, mas em algo mais metódico.

Minha recomendação é identificar através dos requisitos, quais dados são necessários para que o sistema funcione e o relacionamento entre elas. Já dizem os DBAs: *os dados são o coração do sistema*. Assim temos as entidades necessárias.

Depois, com base nas funcionalidades que o sistema deve ter, pode-se então criar classes que serão responsáveis por tratar essas funcionalidades.

Enfim, não há uma resposta absoluta, mas espero ter exemplificado bem um caminho que aprendi ao longo de alguns anos estudando e refletindo sobre como desenvolver bem um software, não só do ponto de vista técnico.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @utluiz! Você clarificou muitos pontos que ficaram confusos em outras leituras que eu fiz. Tem uma coisa ainda que quero te perguntar: em alguns pontos da sua resposta você mencionou equipes. No meu caso, trabalho sozinho. Você poderia recomendar uma referência a respeito desse assunto pra programadores que trabalham sozinhos? Acho que não existe, mas não custa perguntar. Mais uma vez muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @user1620696 Não tenho referência específica sobre o assunto. Eu faço vários projetos sozinho e o que me ajuda é ler sobre organização pessoal e ter em mente que a documentação será para comunicar informações com o "eu do futuro". Eu já tentei fazer documentação detalhada de projetos, mas não deu certo. O que deu certo é simplesmente anotar as coisas importantes para quando precisar retomar aquele ponto do trabalho.

Comment: Queria aproveitar pra perguntar outra coisa @utluiz. Hoje encontrei um livro chamado "Use a cabeça! Análise e Projeto Orientados a Objetos". Dei uma olhada no índice e em algumas páginas e o livro me pareceu bom pra quem está começando no assunto.  Você conhece esse livro? Saberia me dizer se ele é bom ou não? Muito obrigado!

Comment: @user1620696 Sim, já li e recomendo. É uma ótima introdução ao assunto.

Comment: É uma boa resposta mas eu discordo em grau e gênero principalmente com *tl;dr*. Há muitos anos eu tenho observado que **os substantivos e verbos de um código OOP bem desenhado provêm sim do jargão do negócio** e que **a análise do problema e o design da solução estão sim intimamente ligados**. A tal ponte entre o sistema e o negócio deixa de ser necessária se você segue estas premissas. Muito tempo depois de começar a notar isso eu travei conhecimento e me aprofundei em **DDD**, e ele recomenda fortemente e nos ensina justamente a fazer isso: fazer o sistema falar a linguagem do negócio.

Comment: Como desenvolvedores, nos preocupamos demais com tecnologia, mas é a preocupação com o cliente que leva ao sucesso expressivo. Eu tenho me repetido aqui no SOpt o quanto é importante direcionar cada documento, cada diagrama, cada linha de código... **única e exclusivamente ao cliente e suas necessidades**, e da importância da conexão íntima do código com o problema.

Comment: @Caffé Substantivos do jargão de negócios são um péssimo exemplo, pois classes com certos nomes representam muito erroneamente conceitos do mundo real. As pessoas geralmente usam o mesmo termo para se referir a coisas muito diferentes ou ainda termos distintos para se referir à uma mesma coisa. Isso ocorre com diferentes profissionais e empresas da mesma área ou em áreas diferentes dentro de uma empresa ou empresas distintas. Em um projeto não trivial, diferentes programadores entenderão os substantivos de forma diferente e não há dicionário de dados que resista a um projeto médio ou grande.

Comment: @Caffé O que escrevi aqui é um resumo de técnicas reconhecidas de engenharia de software. Eu sei que isso vai muito contra a abordagem *ad hoc* ou *agile* que está na moda hoje, por acharem que metodologias de desenvolvimento tradicionais são engessadas e desnecessárias. Entretanto, toda vez que alguém tenta "escalar" *agile* ou *ad hoc* acaba-se nos mesmos problemas que os bons engenheiros de software conhecem há décadas.

Comment: @Caffé A questão da "ponte" deixar de existir simplesmente é uma utopia. Eu também pensava assim, mas um orientador da pós-graduação, doutor pela USP em Engenharia de Software, que faz pesquisas exatamente sobre esse assunto, convenceu-me do contrário. Um exemplo simples é o conceito de arquitetura emergente do XP. Isto leva muitos a pensar que é possível programar sem fixar uma arquitetura. Na verdade, a única diferença é que no XP a arquitetura fica implícita e distribuída na mente dos programadores. Enfim, a diferença é que se torna explícito em algum documento ou permanece subentendido.

Comment: @Caffé Quanto a satisfazer as necessidades do cliente, enquanto tornar o código mais próximo do jargão possa nos ajudar a pensar (o que me lembra DSLs), isso ainda representaria uma parte muito pequena do problema. Se programar consistisse apenas em representar os elementos relevantes do domínio, ok. Muitos projetos de sistemas assim e vemos classes com nomes parecidos esparramadas por todas as camadas do sistema. Porém, em qualquer sistema mais complexo grande parte do esforço será despendido em tarefas que não tem a ver diretamente com do domínio.

Comment: @Caffé Por exemplo, qualquer sistema web com um número relevante de usuários terá que se preocupar com escalabilidade. Isso traz a tona uso de CDN, programação concorrente, estruturas de dados otimizadas, descentralização dos dados, vários tipos de *cache*, persistência assíncrona, experiência do usuário, monitoramento, *profiling* e... a lista não acaba. Tudo isso é de alguma forma interligado, mesmo que a implementação seja distribuída entre equipes e diferentes bases de código e até micro serviços. O esforço para satisfazer o cliente vai muito além de modelar classes.

Comment: Repito que desde o primeiro momento estou me referindo justamente e apenas a domínios complexos (como disse na minha resposta). Eu trabalho numa instituição financeira global com mais de 200 mil funcionários dos quais 80 mil são de TI (fora terceiros) e onde há desenvolvimento de software espalhado por mais de 70 países - e esta não é a única experiência em sistemas complexos que eu observo durante as minhas repostas. Me parece que nós temos experiências distintas quanto ao sucesso em "escalar" o ágil (entre aspas, como você também usou, pois sabemos que não é bem assim que se faz).

Comment: Sim, o vocabulário de negócio é mal utilizado pelos devs e pelos próprios especialistas em negócio - um estudo de *ubiquitous language* (ver DDD) nos ajuda a entender isso. Os mesmos nomes serem usados para coisas distintas em áreas diferentes também é um situação conhecida. **"Situação"** e não necessariamente problema pois pode fazer sentido para o negócio que seja assim - um estudo de *bounded context* (ver DDD) nos ajuda a enteder isso. Concordo que dicionários de dados nestes casos não resolvem nada - como eu já havia [comentado aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69609/14584).

Comment: Sim, o esforço para satisfazer o cliente vai além de modelar o domínio. Mas reafirmo que modelar o domínio é a parte mais difícil e também a mais importante. Eu posso adicionar muitas tecnologias e arquiteturas para escalar um sistema bem modelado, e para lidar com estas tecnologias *"hard"* eu posso ler manuais e contratar consultores. Mas e para desenhar, refatorar e evoluir a modelagem de um domínio complexo? Manuais e treinamentos contratados no mercado não podem resolver o problema de modelar o negócio do cliente. Repito: precisamos pôr mais foco no negócio do que na tecnologia.

Comment: @Caffé Ao que parece nós poderíamos concordar em 99%, excetuando talvez algumas preferências pessoais. Acho importante reforçar para os demais usuários que em nenhum momento eu defendo que só existe um método válido para modelar um software. Infelizmente este é um problema longe de ser resolvido e mesmo o conhecimento existente é na maioria das vezes mal interpretado e mal empregado. Se eu defendi ardentemente um ponto de vista, não é porque creio ter a razão absoluta, mas por gostar de discutir o assunto.

Comment: **Se gostou da minha resposta, [esta outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91656/227) é leitura obrigatória.**

Answer (score 7):

## TL;DR

> A análise do problema e o design da solução estão profundamente conectados, falam a mesma língua, e somente esta língua (a língua do negócio).

A implementação tecnológica está desconectada desta linguagem.

A resposta do utluiz entrega bastante, mas como eu comentei lá, vejo de maneira diferente alguns aspectos importantes da questão.

## Design do projeto

Vou tentar tentar resumir ao máximo a minha visão.

Por favor tenha em conta que eu me refiro a sistemas minimamente complexos - não falo de "sites" web, sistema de blog, sistemas altamente cadastrais que só tem CRUD...

Eu estou falando de sistemas que possuem **regras de negócio**, e que estas sejam **complexas** (acredite, mesmo com toda a onda de startups, etc, ainda são os sistemas complexos que movem o mundo).

### Modelagem do domínio

Esta parte busca cuidar apenas da regra de negócio. Deve se concentrar ao máximo no negócio.

> Os nomes de objetos, nomes dos seus atributos e comportamentos, **reproduzem fielmente os substantivos e verbos do negócio**.

Esta parte do design da solução, que é escrever as regras de negócio usando a linguagem do negócio, é a parte mais importante do projeto. É aqui que devemos fazer nossos maiores investimentos.

É nesta parte do design que você encontra as classes óbvias que citou (*Produto*, *Forncedor*,...) e também outras não tão óbvias mas que com certeza pode-se achar um nome adequado a partir da conversa com o cliente ou seus especialistas no negócio.

<sub>Importante notar que entidades de nomes iguais aparecem em áreas diferentes do domínio, com propósitos, características e comportamentos distintos. Isso pode ser natural e correto no negócio do cliente e é preciso que a modelagem respeite. Uma abordagem para solucionar isso é usar *contextos delimitados* (ou *bounded context*).</sub>

Além disso, é importante que o projeto esteja apto a mudar estes nomes quando aparecerem outros nomes mais adequados. Essa mudança de nomes podemos chamar de **"refatoramento da modelagem"**.

### Camada de aplicação

Esta parte do design também importa para o negócio e ela conhece a modelagem da solução (embora a modelagem não a conheça).

Aqui você encontra um misto de termos tecnológicos com termos de negócio.

Por exemplo, aqui você econtra um *ProdutoController* com um serviço *RemoverProduto*, que manipula os componentes da modelagem da solução para atender uma requisição do usuário, e depois navega para uma certa página conforme definido com o cliente ou os especialistas de negócio.

Muitos nomes nesta parte do design são dependentes da tecnologia e arquitetura selecionada, mas aqueles que manipulam objetos da modelagem da solução farão alusão aos nomes destes objetos.

### Camadas de apresentação, de infraestrutura e tecnologia da solução

Esta parte também exige um bom design e grandes cuidados; mas a parte mais importante do design, que é a modelagem da solução, está completamente desconectada desta parte aqui de apresentação, infraestrutura e tecnologias.

É nesta parte aqui do design que você mais vai encontrar e escrever classes sem nomes significativos para o negócio.

Palavras como *"table"*, *"connection"*, *"provider"*... aparecem por aqui.

De fato os nomes aqui estão mais relacionados à tecnologia e arquitetura, e isso não é um problema.

## Conclusão

Os maiores investimentos do projeto devem ocorrer na modelagem e implementação da solução, e esta deve sim falar a linguagem do negócio, com seus verbos e substantivos.

Não deveria ser necessária uma ponte entre a parte mais importante do design (a modelagem) e o negócio - ambos deveriam falar a mesma língua.

As demais partes do design vão falar mais a linguagem de arquitetura e tecnologia e menos linguagem do negócio, e isso é natural.

Para a modelagem falar a linguagem do negócio não é fundamental que os programadores sejam especialistas no negócio - eles podem aprender o necessário sobre o negócio durante o projeto.

Se você tem desenvolvedores com as competências certas e pode contar com especialistas no negócio no lado do cliente, a parte do design que modea a solução vai falar a linguagem a linguagem do negócio e estará bastante desconectada da linguagem tecnológica.

Ficou bem maior do que eu gostaria mas espero ter conseguido me expressar. Questionamentos são bem vindos.

Comment: Concordo que a análise e design estejam conectados. Aliás, se todo o processo não estiver conectado e seguir uma única lógica ou regra, há algo muito errado. Infelizmente, isto não é incomum nas empresas e bilhões são desperdiçados todos os anos por causa disso. Entretanto, juntar análise e design num único passo não é uma bala de prata, é simplesmente tentar fazer duas coisas ao mesmo tempo. Para problemas não complexos e não caóticos, pode funcionar bem, assim como quando alguém com facilidade de matemática escreve diretamente a solução sem desenvolver a equação do enunciado.

Comment: Outro problema são os termos que a princípio podem parecer simples e diretos, tal como *Fornecedor* ou *Cliente*. Em cada área da empresa esses termos podem ter significados distintos, a não ser que se esteja copiando os termos já usados em outros sistemas, como ERPs ou CRMs. Neste caso é um problema já resolvido. Mesmo assim, já cansei de ver sistemas que, ao evoluir, tem que trocar os termos usados porque a princípio pensou-se que eram simples, mas depois verificou-se que havia muitas nuances. Então nomes de tabelas, classes e labels ficam inconsistentes, há o modo "antigo" e o "novo".

Comment: Um outro problema que é mais conceitual do que prática e a não existência de uma "ponte" do problema real para a solução. Bem, isso é o mesmo que dizer que as classes de um sistema representam de forma fiel os problemas do cliente. Não existe tal coisa. O que programamos é uma abstração do problema real, geralmente um subconjunto do problema contendo as características relevantes para resolver uma situação particular. Claro que, quanto melhor a modelagem representar o problema, melhor. É como uma equação da Física ou da Química. Enfim, a diferença é a "ponte" ficar mais implícita.

Comment: Independente de minhas críticas, quero dizer que esta resposta é muito boa, no sentido de que uma contraposição a minha reposta inicial permite enriquecer bastante o tema, além de esclarecer que ninguém aqui é a favor de seguir um processo mágico ou gerar burocracia desnecessária. Algo muito importante é que na medida em que vamos entendendo melhor como as coisas funcionam, podemos "*hackear* o sistema" ao invés de seguir cegamente o que outros pregam. Tenho certeza de que o Caffé faz isso e por isso pode falar com propriedade sobre o assunto.

Comment: Sim, me refiro apenas a domínios não triviais (escrevi isso na resposta original). Sim, o jargão de negócio é mal utilizado por devs e também no próprio negócio - e este é um problema conhecido com abordagens de solução disponíveis. Sim, nomes iguais tem significados diferentes em áreas diferentes do domínio - e isso também é uma situação conhecida e com abordagens de solução conhecidas. Sim, o projeto precisa estar apto a ter estes nomes alterados (também escrevi isso na resposta original) e este é um problema relativamente simples de resolver.

Comment: E sim, modelamos apenas um "subconjunto" do problema do cliente, confome eu já [respondi aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90752/14584). E fico feliz que você perceba que minha intenção ao discutir é dar material para pensar, pois problemas interessantes não se resolvem com uma simples resposta no SO, mesmo que longa. E acredito que respostas honestas e contraditórias são ótimas para ajudar a pensar.

Answer (score 5):

Casos de uso são utilizados para mapear o negócio, facilitar a análise das regras de negócio que teu sistema irá ter e começar a mapeá-las em classes, atividades, interfaces de acordo com diagramas de classe, diagramas de atividades, diagramas sequenciais, etc. Afundando da regra de negócios para a tecnologia, conforme o nível de detalhamento que se deseja.

Com esta primeira análise (das regras de negócio) tu vai ter as classes "obvias" do teu sistema, as "menos obvias" não tem outra forma a não ser dominar a tecnologia que tu está utilizando para fazer o sistema. Por isto, imagino eu, que muita gente acha que ser arquiteto ou analista de sistemas é um cargo maior, ou um próximo passo, para um programador/desenvolvedor experiente (algo que não acredito, não vejo mal em um cara que gosta de programar/desenvolver evoluir e manter-se na programação/desenvolvimento), pois, para fazer estes diagramas, estas análises, o arquiteto/analista deve saber como a tecnologia com a qual o sistema será implementado funciona.
Ex: Se vai programar em MVC .NET, sabe que vai ter as classes Model, View e Controller. Se vai programar em Web Form (.NET), como que vai estruturar, vai seguir a ideia do MVC? Vai utilizar DDD (Domain Driven Design)?

RESUMINDO: Tudo depende do nível de detalhamento que tu deseja ter nas análises e nos diagramas, o quanto tu entende da regra de negócios e o quanto tu entende da tecnologia a ser utilizada.