# Existe um modelo para documentar a "Ubiquitous language" no DDD?

Tags: ddd, projeto-de-software

Gostaria de saber se existe um modelo a ser seguido para documentação da `linguagem ubíqua` ou `Ubiquitous language` `DDD`. (linguagem onipresente)

Explicando melhor, seria algo que facilitasse a busca por algum recurso no projeto, evitando assim, a fragmentação ou criação de recursos duplicados.

Espero não está falando besteira pois sou novo na área.

Comment: Eu acho muito estranho documentar a *ubiquitous language*. Ela nasce do jargão do negócio, é a linguagem que deve ser compreendida e falada por todos no projeto, inclusive pelo código, e ela evolui sempre. Não entendi como um documento com o objetivo exclusivo de descrever a *ubiquitous language* poderia ajudar a não criar recursos duplicados no projeto. Poderia explicar mais o seu problema ou objetivo?

Comment: É certo que todos devem compreender e falar a linguagem do projeto, até aí tudo bem, mas por exemplo, focando o código, um desenvolvedor novo chega e vai desenvolver algo relacionado a venda. Como está definido venda neste projeto? `boleto`, `pedido`, `comanda de venda`, `orçamento`? Que documentação ele deve consultar nesta situação? Ou ele deve conversar com alguém  no projeto?

Comment: Ele já conversou com alguém do projeto, ou ele não teria recebido trabalho a fazer. Mesmo que ele tenha apenas lido o texto de um requisito sem conversar com ninguém, se quem escreveu o requisito usou a *ubiquitous language*, no requisito está escrito *"alterar blá-blá-blá na venda"*, então ele encontrará fácil o código que precisa, pois ele vai procurar por *"blá-blá-blá"* dentro de *"venda"*, e não vai perder tempo olhando o código de *"boleto"* ou "*pedido*" porque o requisito que se preocupou em usar a ubiquitous language mencionava apenas os termos de negócio corretos e relevantes.

Comment: Veja: ubiquitous language deve ser falada por todos no projeto, **inclusive o código deve falar a ubiquitous language**.

Comment: Então a documentação do projeto (discutida/documentada,etc), inclusive código, em um projeto que aplique DDD seria suficiente nesse caso?

Comment: Isso! E esta é a maravilha do DDD: depois de ter uma conversa usando apenas um quadro e uma caneta, sem precisar ligar nenhum computador, o novo membro do time já é capaz de se achar no código fonte e de trabalhar no projeto. Não se conversa sobre código e sim sobre arquitetura, design e negócio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No livro `Implementing Domain-Driven Design - Vaughn Vernon` ele sugere como experimento para documentação da linguagem ubíqua o seguinte:

1. Desenhe imagens do domínio físico e conceitual e rotule-os com nomes e
   ações. Estes desenhos são na sua maioria informal, mas pode conter alguns aspectos de modelagem de software formal. 
   Mesmo que sua equipe trabalhe com modelo formal como Unified Modeling Language (UML), deve-se evitar qualquer tipo de ritual que emperre discussões e sufoque a criatividade da Linguagem final que está sendo procurada.
2. Crie um glossário de termos com definições simples. Liste os termos alternativos, incluindo os que são promissores, os que não são, e o por quê. Conforme você inclui definições, você pode não ajudar, mas desenvolve frases reutilizáveis para a Língua porque você é forçado a escrever no idioma do domínio.
3. Mesmo que você não goste da ideia de um glossário, ainda assim se pode capturar algum tipo de documentação com conceitos de software importante.
   Mais uma vez, o objetivo aqui é que venha a tona termos adicionais e frases importantes para a linguagem do domínio.
4. Uma vez que apenas um ou alguns membros da equipe podem capturar o Glossário ou outros documentos escritos, o resto da equipe deve revisar as frases resultantes. Nem sempre, se é que alguma vez, haverá consenso com a a linguística capturada, então, agilidade e correções pesadas são esperadas.

> Estas são ideais básicas com primeiros passos para moldar uma linguagem
>   ubíqua que se encaixa no seu domínio. No entanto, isso
>   absolutamente não é o modelo que você está desenvolvendo. É apenas o
>   início da linguagem ubíqua que deverá ser expressa no
>   código-fonte do seu sistema.

Answer (score 3):

Na área da saúde (um belo exemplo de sistemas complexos) usamos uma "Ubiquitous language" para descrever modelos através da linguagem ADL (Archetype Description Language). Essa linguagem é definida pelo padrão openEHR, que oferece várias ferramentas de documentação e discussão dos modelos entre os especialistas de domínios.

Esta é específica para a área da saúde, mas acredito ser um excelente modelo para o que você está querendo.

Você poderá encontrar material sobre a especificação da linguagem e dos modelos em desenvolvimento em http://www.openehr.org/pt/home

Também encontrará os modelos em desenvolvimento em http://ckm.openehr.org/ckm/

Não sou especialista nas teorias do Eric Evans, mas acredito que existe muita aderência ao que foi proposto por Sam Heard e Thomas Beale.

Veja aqui um pequeno artigo que escrevi sobre desenvolvimento de arquétipos:
**[Proposta Metodológica de Desenvolvimento de Arquétipos](http://www.lbd.dcc.ufmg.br/bdbcomp/servlet/Trabalho?id=11771)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abs