# Domain-Driven Design e levantamento de requisitos

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, arquitetura-de-software, ddd, projeto-de-software, requisitos

Quando utilizamos Domain-Driven Design uma parte importante do processo de desenvolvimento é o contato com especialistas de negócio para ter uma boa compreensão do domínio em questão. Isso pode ser feito, por exemplo, com entrevistas com os especialistas de domínio e pelo que eu sei o principal objetivo é entender o domínio em si nesse momento, as regras e lógicas de negócio e construir uma linguagem ubíqua.

Outro ponto principal para desenvolver um software é conhecer os requisitos do mesmo, principalmente os funcionais. Isso pode ser feito também com entrevistas, procurando saber o que o sistema deve realmente fazer e então escrevendo user stories e casos de uso para detalhar os requisitos.

Ademais, pelo que sei ambos os processos usualmente são iterativos. Ao longo do desenvolvimento procuramos entender cada vez mais o domínio e revisar o conhecimento que já possuíamos e também ao longo do desenvolvimento procuramos entender melhor os requisitos.

Esses dois processos me parecem coisas distintas. No primeiro o objetivo é entender o domínio e no segundo entender o que o software deve fazer. Mas eu fico em dúvida em relação a como conciliar esses dois processos.

O que quero dizer com isso é: o que devemos fazer primeiro? Devemos primeiro tentar conhecer um pouco do domínio e depois começar a coletar os requisitos ou devemos primeiro tentar compreender os requisitos e depois começar a conhecer o domínio? Ou de alguma forma esses dois processos são realizados de forma simultanea?

Em síntese, como se pode conciliar, de maneira eficiente, o processo de coleta de requisitos e de entendimento do domínio?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interessante você enxergar entendimento do domínio e levantamento de requisitos como dois processos distintos. Eu nunca vi desta maneira. Para mim, o conhecimento do domínio vem **durante** o levantamento de requisitos.

Mas eu estou usando "levantamento de requisitos" aqui com um sentido bastante amplo e não sei se estamos alinhados, então permita-me detalhar um pouco.

## O que o cliente sabe

O cliente nunca sabe, adiantadamente, o que exatamente ele precisa em termos de software, mas ele sempre sabe o que ele precisa em termos de negócio e ele tem alguma idéia de onde um software se enquadra na solução do problema.

Então o cliente vem até nós com uma necessidade do tipo:

> *"A máquina que enche estes containers deve saber por conta própria o quanto de material colocar em cada um, pois hoje isso é controlado por um funcionário e é difícil acertar a quantidade exata."*

## Etapas do levantamento de requisitos

O que eu entendo por levantamento de requisitos começa aqui.

### Capacidade desejada

O que o cliente sabe que precisa podemos chamar de ***"capacidade"***.

O cliente acabou de nos contar a nova capacidade que ele deseja ter no seu sistema. Veja como a necessidade pode ser reescrita usando esta palavra:

> *"A máquina que enche estes containers deve ter a **capacidade** de acertar a quantidade exata de material a colocar em cada um sem depender da intervenção do funcionário."*

### Entendimento do domínio

Agora, para descobrir como fazer um software que entregue a capacidade desejada, precisamos entender o domínio.

O processo de entendimento do domínio é um trabalho realizado em função de descobrir os requisitos de software, e é limitado a atender esta função.

**Isso significa que o time de software não está interessado em conhecer toda a operação do cliente**; então o time de software não vai passar dias em reuniões com os especialistas no negócio para se tornar tão especialista quanto eles.

Em vez disso, o time vai procurar saber dos especialistas como o funcionário decide a quantidade de material em cada container; de modo a entender quais são as entradas disponíveis para o novo software.

O time vai procurar aprender também como o funcionário opera a máquina quando decide interromper o trabalho de encher um container; de modo a entender quais são as saídas que o novo software deve produzir.

De início, o time não está interessado em nada mais além da operação daquela máquina em particular, e ele só vai estender o seu aprendizado para outros detalhes da operação do cliente se isso se revelar necessário durante este esforço de entender a máquina. Em princípio, o **domínio** do problema é apenas a operação da máquina.

> Então podemos concluir que **domínio** é área de conhecimento do problema que o software pretende resolver. Domínio não é o conhecimento de toda a operação do cliente.

Enquanto aprende sobre a máquina, o time começa a exercitar a *ubiquitous language*. A linguagem começa a ser elaborada durante o trabalho de desenhar os primeiros requisitos.

### Requisitos de software

> Um requisito de software é um dos recursos que o software deve oferecer. O conjunto de todos os requisitos de software deve entregar a capacidade desejada.

Em DDD, é impossível formular um requisito de software sem a *ubiquitous language*. Mas a construção da *ubiquitous language* não é um processo à parte.

A construção da *ubiquitous language* ocorre durante o esforço de formular os requisitos de software.

## Conclusão

- O objetivo do projeto de software é entregar uma **capacidade** (eventualmente mais de uma).
- **Domínio** é a área de conhecimento das capacidades que devem ser entregues pelo software.
- A ***ubiquitous language*** é construída durante o esforço de formular os requisitos de software, ela é aprimorada durante a elaboração de cada requisito, e a elaboração dos requisitos ocorre ao longo de todo o projeto.
- **Requisito de software** é um dos recursos que o software deve oferecer.
- O **conjunto** de todos os requisitos de software deve entregar a capacidade desejada.
- O aprendizado do domínio e a decorrente construção da *ubiquitous language* acontece **em função do levantamento de requisitos**, durante o levantamento de requisitos, e é delimitada pela capacidade desejada.

Podemos dizer que o conhecimento do domínio e a decorrente construção da *ubiquitous language* são "puxados"* pela necessidade de levantar requisitos.

<sub>*Ver *push system* ou *sistema puxado*, que em suma é "fazer o necessário apenas quando necessário e apenas na quantidade necessária".</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que um boa maneira de conciliar ambas as definições *(Domínio e Regras de Negócio)* seja a utilização das práticas de DDD com BDD **(Specification By Example)**. Como podemos ver na imagem abaixo, eles agem sobre os mesmo conceitos, porém com abordagens diferentes:

[image: BDD x DDD (Fonte: www.infoq.com/news/2015/02/bdd-ddd)]

Considerando isto, e usando a linguagem [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin), podemos definir um requisito de negócio definido da seguinte forma:

```
Cenario: Comer 5 de 12
  Dado que existam 12 pepinos
  Quando eu comer 5 pepinos
  Então devem existir 7 pepinos
```

Então agora você tem um requisito, que utiliza os objetos de domínio para ser válido, você foi explicado sobre um exemplo de como deveria funcionar, agora você deve definir bem cada objeto relacionado.