# Orientação a objeto - Como encontrar as abstrações corretas?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, independente-de-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação

Na verdade a pergunta que estou querendo fazer é exatamente essa: [Como identificar classes em um sistema orientado a objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14990/como-identificar-classes-em-um-sistema-orientado-a-objetos). Porém gostaria de pedir duas complementações à resposta aceita dela.

1. Ela parece descrever o chamado OOA&D (Object-Oriented Analysis and Design) ou Análise e Projeto Orientados a Objeto. Não sei se esta é uma solicitação adequada ao formato do SO, mas eu gostaria de pedir uma referência canônica a respeito do assunto, e aceitando material complementar ao canônico (se possível indicando por que eu deveria preferir um material em relação a outro). Se fizer diferença, tenho maior experiência com Java. Atualmente estou em dúvida entre as seguintes referências:

   - **Applying UML and Patterns** (Craig Larman) - livro-texto adotado pela minha universidade após eu me formar; parece não entrar muito em detalhes no que diz respeito a encontrar as abstrações corretas, mas em seu texto o autor recomenda o Responsibility-Driven Design que é descrito no livro abaixo;
   - **Object Design: Roles, Responsibilities, and Collaborations** (Rebecca Wirfs-Brock, Alan McKean) - a autora é referência em OO; o livro introduz o RDD, que parece ser preciso sobre como escolher as abstrações corretas na hora de modelar as classes;
   - **Object-Oriented Software Construction** (Bertrand Meyer) - o autor é referência em OO, mas a última edição não é muito recente;
   - **Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications** (Grady Booch et al.) - interessante porque compara abordagens clássicas e modernas para Análise Orientada a Objeto e dedica o capítulo 4 a "encontrar as abstrações corretas";
   - **Head First Object-Oriented Analysis & Design** (Brett D. McLaughlin et al) - nenhuma recomendação especial, só gosto do estilo da série Head First.
2. Uma pergunta mais específica a respeito da modelagem das classes. Confesso que apesar de achar que "programava OO" há muitos anos, pelo fato de ter estudado minha disciplina de POO, aprendido minha cota de *design patterns*, lido sobre SOLID, conhecer coesão/acoplamento, favorecer composição a herança e tudo mais, na verdade tinha muita liberdade com minhas classes e não entendia realmente a filosofia original por trás da orientação a objeto. Se entendesse, saberia há tempos o motivo de fazerem sentido certas *"rules of thumb"* como [Tell Don't Ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) (que em sua forma mais amena adverte contra o vazamento de lógica de negócio para fora do objeto por meio de *getters* desnecessários) ou [the er-er Principle](http://www.carlopescio.com/2011/04/your-coding-conventions-are-hurting-you.html), ou ainda a postagem [Dance You Imps](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/10/01/Dance-You-Imps.html) do Robert Martin. Objetos vão além de juntar estado e comportamento à revelia da nossa intuição e experiência individual; eles seriam mais como "mini-máquinas" que fornecem uma API de *comandos* para seus clientes (seus métodos públicos, que via de regra devem ser mais de um; caso contrário provavelmente é uma *procedure* disfarçada de objeto), deixam transparecer um mínimo de estado (*isso* é encapsulamento; não tem nada a ver com simplesmente criar *getters* para variáveis privadas) e se autogerenciam. Você não *cria* classes à sua revelia; você *acha* as classes que são mais apropriadas, muitas vezes tendo que descartar as escolhas inicialmente mais óbvias. Para mim esses conceitos não são nada intuitivos e acredito que haja material a respeito de como projetar classes corretamente seja nos livros acima ou em algum outro lugar, por isso a pergunta-título: "Como encontrar as abstrações corretas?", que deve levar em conta essa correta filosofia de orientação a objeto. Na verdade gostaria de quebrar essa pergunta em duas partes: uma voltada para o longo prazo, na qual as respostas indicam leitura sobre o assunto; e uma para o curto prazo, visto que estou iniciando a codificação de um projeto novo, com regras de negócio, arquitetura, modelagem de banco e serviços individuais já especificados e desde que constatei essa deficiência estou me sentindo inseguro a respeito de como projetar as classes dentro desses serviços. Visto que a filosofia correta não é intuitiva para tantos programadores (é o que dizem os entendidos do assunto, e o que atesta o desconhecimento amplo desse material canônico que o @Maniero falou, e vide também a errônea analogia de que os objetos devem refletir precisamente o mundo real [[1]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/does-object-oriented-programming-really-model-the-real-world) [[2]](http://www.wirfs-brock.com/PDFs/013-015.pdf)), e visto que criar o *seu* diagrama de classes por intuição em vez de achar o mais apropriado também é incorreto, encontrar as abstrações certas parece um bocado mais difícil do que antes.

Comment: É fácil encaixar esse tipo de pergunta. Peça uma referência canônica sobre o assunto ao invés de pedir "um monte de material", e diga que aceita materiais complementares ao canônico. Sabendo fazer, não dando  margem para resposta sem sentido, qualquer coisa dá para ser perguntada. Você está descobrindo, não sei se para o bem ou para o mal que OOP é vendida como algo mágico e universal e que não é bem assim. Não sei se está indo para um caminho melhor ou pior. Se agora vai complicar ainda mais seus códigos para consertar os erros de OOP, ou vai começar fazer uso parcimonioso do paradigma.

Comment: Fazer OOP correto é tão complicado e tão difícil de ensinar que já deveria acender uma luz vermelha se ele deveria ser usado de forma ostensiva como muitos fazem. É claro que se o problema consegue se adaptar bem de forma intuitiva ao paradigma, é um bom indicador que ele é adequado. Eu não entendo porque as pessoas vivem dando murro em ponta de prego. Se está difícil entender é porque é difícil de aplicar. A cultura do monoparadigma não está fazendo os softwares ficarem melhores. O "real world" foi muito usado para vender o paradigma, para mostrar como ele entraria fácil na cabeça das pessoas

Comment: Ok, então vou pedir uma referência canônica e aceitar materiais complementares ao canônico. Se fizer diferença, a minha experiência maior é com Java.

Comment: Sobre referências de livros "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" (clássico) e "Head First Design Patterns" (basicamente o anterior simplificado) estão entre os melhores sobre OO que já li. Agora como o @bigown falou OOP é superestimada, se você quer fazer código decente de verdade tem que se expor a vários paradigmas e melhorar o máximo possível sua lógica e conhecimento de algoritmos.

Comment: @BrunoRB Complementei na pergunta que já conheço design patterns, na verdade tenho esses dois livros. Mas o que estou perguntando é sobre orientações mais gerais do que design patterns. Sobre os paradigmas você tem razão, mas particularmente prefiro dominar OO antes de partir para o funcional, por exemplo.

Comment: Como seria algo incompleto pra você, resolvi colocar como um comentário e não uma resposta. Sugiro uma literatura muito interessante que apresenta muito bem os desafios e as maneiras de pensar quando trilhamos o caminho da programação, aplicando OO ou não: The Pragmatic Programmer de Andrew Hunt e David Thomas. É um livro bem mais alto nível no que tange as filosofias de programação. Inclusive recomendo que voce procure bibliografias menos "técnicas", já que seu problema me parece muito mais conceitual.

Comment: @Thiesen Não entendi o que você quis dizer com conceitual. Meu problema é exatamente técnico.

Comment: @bigown Você diz que devido à cultura monoparadigma existem problemas que não deveriam estar sendo resolvidos com o paradigma OO. Isso é um ponto. Além disso, na sua opinião para o caso geral qual paradigma deveria dominar? Ou então qual solução multiparadigma? Ou talvez nem exista caso geral?

Comment: Nenhum. O domínio seria ruim. Eu sempre gostei do procedural/modular, mas uso bastante OOP. Lembrando que linha por linha, o grosso do que fazemos é imperativo. Eu tenho gostado cada vez mais do funcional. Tem outros interessantes mas que é difícil de engolir. Mas eu achava o funcional difícil também e cada vez acho menos. Tem um monte de paradigma mais limitado que são interessantes. A maioria podem ser usados para complementar outros, tipo: genérico, meta, contratos, eventos, aspectos, concorrencial, etc.

Comment: O funcional s/ radicalismos, aceitando um pouco de imperativo, c/ alternativas e escapes p/ OOP acho que pode ser a melhor opção moderna em termos gerais. Mas ainda estou melhorando minha formação nesta área. Não tenho condições de cravar uma posição definitiva. O que sei é que OOP tem problemas demais para ser usado como *default*. Funcional é chatinho no começo, mas conforme vai avançando, vê que não é tanto, aconteceu isso com OOP. Na verdade OOP é tão complicado que quase ninguém sabe usar direito. Procedual certo não é tão óbvio, precisa de bastante experiência.

Comment: Ou seja, programar é difícil e nada faz mágica. O paradigma não ajuda o programador evitar bobagens, só expressar melhor certos padrões. A tipagem, a forma de gerenciar memória, um bom compilador e outras ferramentas ajudam o programador mais que outro paradigma. Eu acho que ainda faltam boas linguagens na maioria dos paradigmas, o funcional pegaria melhor se houvesse mais linguagens menos radicais. Claro que o funcional não resolve tudo bem também. Mas tenho visto linguagens mixando bem as coisas. Algumas se tivessem mais bom gosto e um apoio corporativo das *big techies*, iriam pra frente.

Comment: Nesse ponto seria bom se as linguagens tivessem a característica de promover a correta aplicação do paradigma.

Comment: É, isso não é possível. Os paradigmas tentam ajudar mas há limitações. Você recebeu uma resposta que fa o que OOP faz melhor, se vender bem. Dá uma definição genérica do que é OOP. Assim ele cabe em qualquer coisa. Aí você vai codificar só olhando para esta definição, e ela não ajuda em nada. Mas por outro lado se isto for OOP, qualquer linguagem é OOP porque pode representar o mundo real em qualquer paradigma.Você recebeu a resposta que eu espera,uma que não ajuda em nada a melhorar o entendimento sobre isto.E pra variar mistura coisas e coloca relações que não existem,além de inconsistências

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Design orientado a objetos: contexto histórico e situação atual

No início dos anos 90 houve uma explosão de metodologias de desenvolvimento de aplicações orientadas a objetos competindo entre si, muitas com ferramentas CASE próprias, denominada *"method wars"*. Dentre os livros citados na pergunta, o *Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications* descreve o método de Booch, e o *Object Design* é a versão atualizada do método RDD, proposto inicialmente no livro *Designing Object-Oriented Software*. Destacam-se também o OMT, de James Rumbaugh, e o OOSE, de Ivar Jacobson. [1](https://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBC31/Overheads/L6_new.pdf) [2](http://www.uni-ulm.de/~sbauer/programming/OOinfo/FAQ/oo-faq-S-3.7.html)

Booch, Rumbaugh e Jacobson (*"the three amigos"*) se juntaram com a intenção de desenvolver um método unificado, mas o que se destacou foi a criação de uma notação unificada para seus e outros métodos individuais, a UML (*Unified Modeling Language*).
 [3](http://www.inf.ufpr.br/silvia/ES/UML/pdf/IntroduzUMLAl.pdf)

Permanece portanto a questão de qual dos métodos utilizar, em paralelo com a crescente adoção de métodos/frameworks de desenvolvimento de software ágeis que não estabelecem uma abordagem de design específica. Os métodos dos anos 90 são considerados mais *"planned design"*, em oposição ao chamado *"evolutionary/continuous/emerging design"* que pode ser feito mais *ad hoc* durante o desenvolvimento. Martin Fowler sugere combinar as duas abordagens. [4](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/designDead.html)

Se houver algo errado por favor me corrijam.

### Pontos específicos

Vou terminar de responder a pergunta com o que aprendi até o momento após algumas verificações e corrigindo algumas impressões erradas que tinha quando a fiz.

- Para um problema há muitas soluções razoáveis e algumas ótimas. Além disso, diferentes abordagens de design (RDD, DDD, etc.) [podem até mesmo ser combinadas entre si](http://manclswx.com/workshops/splash12/rebecca_talk_summary.html) de maneira benéfica. Então o @utluiz está certo, não existe um design correto e nem um material canônico, temos que ler o máximo que pudermos a respeito do assunto. Frequentemente porém, diz a Rebecca, você primeiro faz o código funcionar e depois se preocupa em tornar os objetos mais simples.
- Sim, objetos são como mini-máquinas, mas não existe nenhum impedimento quanto a eles fornecerem um só comando. O princípio *er-er* na verdade não generaliza a ideia de que objetos terminados em *-er* são ruins, essa é uma interpretação errada do mesmo. Bertrand Meyer alerta para objetos com um comando só mas apenas no caso em que eles não têm sequer um construtor parametrizado (aí sim provavelmente se trata de um procedimento disfarçado de objeto).
- O espírito do princípio *Tell Don't Ask* (manter no mesmo lugar os dados e os comportamentos que os manipulam) é bom e válido para o caso geral segundo Fowler e Rebecca, mas há algumas situações em que é interessante separá-los (por exemplo, no padrão *Specification* do DDD).
- Pessoalmente tenho o hábito quase automático de aplicar DRY assim que aparece o primeiro sinal de duplicação no código, criando funções ou novas hierarquias de classes. Isso é parte do meu problema ao dizer que crio classes à revelia, e tem o nome de *generalização prematura*. Toda decisão de design deve ser tomada com cuidado porque engessa o código e gera um efeito cascata em outras decisões de design. Há então momentos em que é melhor deixar a duplicidade acontecer por um tempo até se ter uma boa visão do código para que a decisão de generalizar seja mais acertada.

Answer (score 7):

Vou arriscar uma resposta simplista à pergunta principal:

> Como encontrar as abstrações corretas?

## Abordagem top-down

Numa reflexão pessoal, cheguei à conclusão de que uma das formas de resolver problemas que é mais eficiente para mim consiste numa abordagem *top-down*, indo do conceito mais abstrato e genérico para o mais concreto e específico.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que o cliente quer um programa para controlar um robô que prepara sucos. Voltando ao princípio mais básico da computação (*entrada, processamento e saída*), eu tenho:

- Entradas: frutas, água e açúcar (ingredientes)
- Processamento: robô usa o liquitificador, podem haver diferentes tipos de "receitas"
- Saída: bebida

Então, em alto nível, posso determinar a interface principal do sistema:

```
class Robo {
    Suco preparar(Ingredientes, Procedimento)
]
```

Basicamente, você pede ao Robô para fazer o suco, fornece os ingredientes e diz qual o procedimento, recebendo como resultado a vitamina.

Claro, é algo muito simples, mas aqui está a vantagem. Uma boa modelagem, na definição que estou usando, inclui dois elementos principais:

1. O fato de muitos detalhes não estarem representados dão grande **liberdade à forma como tudo será implementado**. Os processos podem ser quebrados em subprocessos, objetos mais abstratos podem ser compostos com outros objetos mais simples, as interfaces ou classes principais podem ter versões especializadas, as interações entre os elementos não estão totalmente definidas e assim por diante.
2. Ao mesmo tempo temos uma "interface pública" bem definida para os "clientes" dessa classe fazerem suas vitaminas.

Resumindo:

> A abstração "correta" seria a que permite você implementar e especializar as funcionalidades existentes com liberdade sem mudar os níveis mais altos.

## Considerações

### Orientação a objetos vs. outros paradigmas

Em várias questões que tem surgido esses dias, tem sido levantada a questão de vantagens da POO contra algum outro paradigma.

De forma alguma devemos ver isso como uma competição. Os diferentes paradigmas podem e devem ser usados em conjunto.

A POO, com suas classes e atributos não substitui a programação "procedural" ou imperativa nem impede o uso de programação funcional, mas adiciona capacidades de encapsulamento e abstração que seriam mais difíceis de expressar nos demais paradigmas.

Nada impede, por exemplo, que um código "procedural" construa uma coleção de objetos e execute uma operação de *map-reduce* para obter uma consolidação dos dados da coleção.

### Estruturas de dados vs abstração

Note que na minha "modelagem", nem entrei na questão das estruturas de dados utilizadas, isto é, quais atributos representam um ingrediente, etc.

O trunfo da POO não é em organizar conjuntos de dados, nem (na minha opinião) em representar entidades da vida real, mas sim na abstração ou no que é possível especificar **sem definir** os detalhes.

Os atributos da vida real podem ser representados em estruturas de dados "sem vida" e processadas por funções ou rotinas independentes.

Por outro lado a elegância de uma boa modelagem de classes está, na minha opinião, não na modelagem em si, mas no quão fácil e intuitiva ela é para as outras pessoas que irão acessar, implementar e estender. Disto, nenhuma linguagem puramente procedural chegou perto até hoje.

### Tornando o conhecimento concreto

Não irei recomendar uma literatura específica do assunto. Na verdade, não conheço e não acho que exista nada que seja definitivo. Qualquer texto ou livro vai abordar no máximo alguns aspectos do que é modelar o problema em objetos.

A única forma que conheço para fazer uma modelagem "correta" é:

1. Ler tudo o que puder sobre o assunto
2. Tentar aplicar isso num problema da melhor forma que você conseguir
3. Fazer prova de uso na prática e recolher feedback
4. Identificar os problemas e pesquisar em soluções para eles
5. Refazer o modelo tentando resolver os itens encontrados no item #4 para ter uma modelagem "mais correta"
6. Repetir tudo dezenas de vezes

### Um processo criativo

Ao contrário do que está descrito na pergunta, eu não diria que alguém *encontra* a abstração correta, como se isso fosse algo que existe independente do programador.

Programar é um processo criativo. Um artista não encontra a forma correta para pintar ou modelar algo, ele o faz arbitrariamente dentro dos limites que ele se impõe e, é claro, dentro de sua própria capacidade.

Comment: Excelente ponto: "modelagem intuitiva - disto, nenhuma linguagem puramente procedural chegou perto até hoje". Eu posso tentar representar objetos do domínio em programação procedural, usar ponteiros para simular polimorfismo, etc., mas no final não estarei usando o paradigma mas apenas escrevendo código demais para tentar simulá-lo. E se a linguagem não oferece suporte a OOP estou tentando forçar um paradigma num universo onde ele não é bem vindo.

Answer (score 5):

Apesar de muita gente interpretar de maneira simplória o versinho **"Orientação a Objetos ajuda a representar o mundo real"**, o fato é que é exatamente esta idéia que vai te ajudar a encontrar as abstrações corretas.

## Desmistificando a "representação do mundo real"

- O mapa com os nomes de ruas e bairros colado na parede lá em casa representa a minha cidade real?
- O molde em gesso que meu dentista fez representa a minha boca real?
- A planta que o arquiteto fez do prédio onde eu trabalho representa o lugar real onde eu trabalho?

A resposta para todas essas perguntas é **sim e não**:

- O mapa me ajuda a achar um endereço mas não me diz quais ruas possuem boas calçadas para eu poder ir a pé tranquilo.
- O molde do dentista ajuda-o a resolver problemas da minha dentição mas não poderia ajudar outro médico a diagnosticar um problema na mucosa.
- A planta arquitetônica do prédio onde eu trabalho ajuda numa reforma ou na redisposição dos móveis mas não fala nada sobre a refrigeração no escritório, o relacionamento entre as pessoas, os projetos em que trabalhamos, etc.

Ou seja:

> Um modelo representa de fato um objeto do mundo real, segundo a perspectiva ou abstração que interessa para a solução de um problema em específico.

Nenhum tipo de modelo neste universo é capaz de representar um objeto com todas as suas características e funções. Nenhum modelo é capaz nem mesmo de representar apenas as características e funções mais importantes de um objeto!

Cada modelo precisa representar apenas as características e funções de um objeto que **interessam na solução de um problema em específico**. Para isso que serve a OOP e é com esta idéia em mente que você conseguirá encontrar as abstrações corretas.

A este conjunto mínimo, ridiculamente pequeno, de características e funções dos objetos reais que nos interessam ao desenhar uma solução, podemos chamar de *domínio do problema*; ou, para brevidade, podemos chamar apenas de **domínio**.

Já o desenho da solução, a tradução do domínio para objetos, podemos chamar de **modelo**, e a atividade de desenhar o modelo podemos chamar de ***modelagem***.

Creio que o que escrevi até agora você já sabia, mas é bom alinhar. De modo que você sabe também que o próximo tópico, em vez de se chamar *Como transformar o mundo real em um modelo de objetos*, ele se chama:

## Como modelar o domínio?

Orientação a Objetos não é o mais difícil.

Representar o mundo real (dentro do conceito já explicado aqui) usando orientação a objetos também não é.

O que é mais difícil é convencer o programador a esquecer a tecnologia por um momento e se concentrar no problema do mundo real que precisa ser resolvido.

Quando o tópico é "orientação a objetos", ouve-se muito as pessoas falando em "herança", "polimorfismo", "interface", "generics", "ORM"...

Programadores não gastam um minuto a mais para entender mais a fundo um requisito de negócio, mas não se importam de gastar horas tentando mapear via ORM uma herança de entidades (desnecessária) para o banco de dados.

Acontece que são os requisitos de negócio, o domínio do problema, que vai entregar as informações que você precisa para encontrar as abstrações corretas.

> A conversa cuidadosa sobre o domínio, com pessoas que entendam do domínio, vai revelar os nomes dos objetos, as delimitações destes objetos, seus atributos e funções; e vai revelar também as interações entre estes objetos e como eles devem ser coordenados para a solução do problema.

Muitos programadores impõem sobre si mesmos a crença limitadora de que o cliente não sabe o que quer. Trabalhar com esta premissa leva a softwares mal desenhados, excessivamente complexos, marcados pelo desperdício e que não resolvem bem o problema.

Envolver o cliente (ver *"product owner"* e *"domain experts"*) é o que vai ajudar a compreender o domínio e portanto a identificar as abstrações corretas.

## Conhecimento e experiência

É claro que conhecimento técnico de orientação a objetos é indispensável, pois o *domain expert* não vai te ensinar a programar.

Conhecimento de design patterns (conhecimento formal ou só por experiência mesmo), também é fundamental para você tomar boas decisões sobre como coordenar o trabalho dos objetos.

> Mas este tipo de conhecimento técnico não é o que vai determinar uma modelagem boa ou ruim; ele é apenas pré-requisito. O fator determinante é o conhecimento do domínio e, lógico, a aplicação deste conhecimento na modelagem.

Como material de estudo, se você já tem experiência com OOP e design patterns e tudo o mais, recomendo o [Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), do Eric Evans.

Eu indico este livro quando o programador já atingiu a maturidade de perceber que seu conhecimento técnico não está sendo suficiente para projetar e implementar com sucesso um grande software.

É sempre bom lembrar que toda a filosia contida neste livro só faz sentido em domínios complexos (que não é o caso por exemplo de pequenos aplicativos mobile, sites web mais cadastrais ou de consulta, ou mesmo sistemas grandes e distribuídos com milhões de usuários mas com baixa complexidade de negócio).

Comment: O cliente pode até saber o que quer, mas não sabe entregar os requisitos mastigados; um termo do domínio pode significar uma coisa para um departamento e outra para outro, e pior, tudo é descrito em linguagem natural. Substantivos candidatos podem estar disfarçados de verbos e é tarefa do desenvolvedor traduzir esse amontoado de informações em requisitos específicos usando uma linguagem não-ambígua. Creio que nisso estamos de acordo, correto? Mas isso eu pelo menos dou como pré-requisito se a pessoa se dispõe a produzir um software. Errado é não entender o domínio direito. Além disso...

Comment: ...a Rebecca defende que nem tudo precisa ter uma contraparte no mundo real. _"[Stop trying to model the real world. It’s a myth that objects should accurately reflect real-world things](http://www.wirfs-brock.com/PDFs/013-015.pdf)"_. O que o DDD fala sobre as abstrações? Ela defende que _"existem diversas abstrações razoáveis, e algumas muito boas"_. Eu entendo que ela fala isso depois do problema ter sido definido, em requisitos e termos não-ambíguos. E por fim, atente para o que objetos não são; escrevi todo um texto a respeito, que vou tentar descrever melhor depois de ler um pouco mais.

Comment: @Piovezan Sim, um mesmo termo tem significados diferentes em diferentes contextos do mesmo domínio, mas a modelagem precisa respeitar isso em vez de tentar evitar (veja *"bounded contexts"*). E não, não estamos de acordo que caiba ao desenvolvedor resolver a ambiguidade: cabe ao dev. **entender** a ambiguidade e **junto** com o especialista no domínio estabelecer a linguagem (nomes e verbos) que será usada por todos, inclusive no código. O cliente não entrega os requisitos mastigados mas ele é a chave, temos que ouvi-lo para mastigar os requisitos e não tentar preenchermos sozinhos os furos.

Comment: É isso que chamo de resolver a ambiguidade: entender a ambiguidade, entender as diferenças, e estabelecer termos não-ambíguos.

Comment: @Piovezan Você diz que "é errado não entender o domínio" mas considerar que cabe ao dev. resolver as ambiguidades e ver na linguagem natural do domínio um problema, se isso não constitui um não entendimento do domínio então é ainda pior: constitui desrespeito ao domínio. Quanto à Rebecca, ela só está concordando comigo: como eu disse na resposta, nenhum modelo na face da terra (nem de OOP nem nenhum outro) é feito para representar acuradamente o mundo real; mas sim apenas o domínio do problema.

Comment: Entendi. O dev não deve estabelecer os termos não-ambíguos sozinho. Mas não estou dizendo que a linguagem natural do domínio é um problema, e sim que implementar o sistema depende dos termos não-ambíguos. Como também depende dos ambíguos.

Comment: Seria assim? "Programadores não gastam um minuto a mais para entender um requisito _e estabelecer junto com o especialista no domínio a linguagem não-ambígua necessária para modelar o problema_ (...)". Senão dá a impressão que ele não tenta sequer estabelecê-la sozinho.

Comment: @Piovezan Pode ser. O ponto principal é que a resposta para encontrar as abstrações corretas está no conhecimento do domínio do problema, no respeito e aplicação da linguagem do domínio  ao codificar; e não simplesmente na experiência com tecnologia. É claro que tendo acesso ao conhecimento do domínio você ainda vai precisar de algumas técnicas, daí design patterns e conceitos de OOP e de DDD vão ajudar.

Comment: Interessante, mas vocês não diriam que o próprio conceito de Design Patterns, diga-se de forma sucinta "Soluções reutilizáveis para problemas que ocorrem com frequência em projetos de software", nada mais é do que a personificação documentada da experiência em modelagem de sistemas, e, por consequência, em tecnologia? Sem contar no fato que conhecer Design Patterns é uma coisa, por que ler o livro é fácil, saber aplicá-los de forma a resolver o problema do seu domínio também remete a experiência e vivência em modelagem e desenvolvimento.

Comment: Não julgo as técnicas aqui apresentadas, e confesso que achei legal ler a respeito de algo que nunca tinha pensado de forma tão técnica assim. Mas eu ainda acho que o papel da vivência tem muito mais importância do que o que vem sendo colocado. Não subestimaria isso de forma nenhuma.

Comment: @Thiesen Como você sabe _design patterns_ ajudam em situações específicas, não no sistema todo. E quanto aos princípios por trás deles, são válidos mas usá-los não te ensina o _core_ do que é um objeto. Leia minha pergunta, eu tenho evidência que um objeto é algo mais específico do que as aulas de OO nos levaram a crer. _"Comandos via de regra são mais de um caso contrário provavelmente são procedures disfarçadas"_ eu tirei do [Bertrand Meyer](https://archive.eiffel.com/doc/manuals/technology/oosc/finding/page.html). E objetos devem ser _achados_, não _inventados_. Os Wirfs-Brock dizem isso.

Comment: Claro que experiência é importante. Dissecar os requisitos passados pelo cliente na linguagem dele, achar a linguagem não-ambígua, tudo isso envolve experiência. Até mesmo a forma como se aplica a técnica de _achar_ os objetos deve ser afetada pela experiência. Mas sem se atentar a esses conceitos _core_ que citei ela está sendo mal aplicada.

Comment: Eu entendo que essa resposta do @Caffé é válida mas nos leva só até certo ponto. Tem coisas que para o cliente são uma caixa preta e esses conceitos não se aplicam. Eu tenho um microserviço que para o cliente é indiferente como vai ser implementado. Esse microserviço recebe comandos via socket. Esses comandos precisam ser _parseados_ para depois serem entendidos e processados. Mas devo criar uma classe verbal `Parser` com um método `parse()` para fazer isso? O Bertrand Meyer diz que não. Isso é intuitivo para você? Porque para mim não é.

Comment: @Piovezan Não se esqueça que a sua pergunta pede uma referência e a minha resposta indicou um livro de 560 páginas, que obviamente eu não vou reescrever aqui. A minha resposta leva até o ponto que ela se propõe: indicar um caminho. Eu tenho a resposta para o seu problema de modelar o serviço que responde por socket (acho que o livro te ajudará a encontrar esta resposta também), mas quem sabe você faz outra pergunta sobre isso, e quem sabe eu responda...

Comment: Se eu fizer a pergunta vou ficar contente se você puder responder. O DDD parece de fato ter uma abordagem de design que é o MDD (Model-Driven Design). Eu penso em comparar com algumas outras na ordem em que foram surgindo, ou seja, o MDD deve ficar por último. É interessante que a Rebecca [faz uma comparação](http://manclswx.com/workshops/splash12/index.html) das diferentes abordagens "xDD" e entre outras conclusões acredita que a escolha mais apropriada depende do cenário e que algumas podem ser combinadas entre si.

Comment: Correção: DDD e MDD são coisas distintas. Eu só não entendo por que o livro do DDD tem uma seção que se chama _The Building Blocks of Model-driven Design_. Eles têm algum grau de parentesco em que um é derivado do outro de alguma maneira?

Comment: @Piovezan Pois é, o universo do desenvolvimento de software não segue uma linguagem ubíqua hehehe. De fato *Model-driven Design* está no core do DDD, mas a sigla MDD pode ter sido usada por aí com variações também. Tem vários MD-blás por aí. Tem um por exemplo que sugere que o sistema seja todo desenhado em diagramas e daí o software ou uma parte dele é gerada a partir destes diagramas e isso por exemplo não faz parte do DDD.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, apesar de achar que nenhuma resposta seja adequada pra sua pergunta, vou arriscar ajudar voce no caminho que voce deseja trilhar.

A resposta direta pra sua pergunta "Como identificar classes em um sistema orientado a objetos?", seria "o que fizer sentido no que diz respeito a separação de responsabilidades da sua aplicação, com foco em reuso buscando não duplicar código desnecessário".

Em um contexto mais amplo, a identificação de classes em uma aplicação, apesar de algumas técnicas passadas por alguns autores possam te ajudar de diversas formas, no final das contas é realmente a sua experiência e visão sistêmica que vão bater o martelo.

Eu diria que identificar essas classes e a relação entre elas (herança, polimorfismo, atributos) é uma combinação de bom senso, conhecimento e principalmente, **experiência**.

Eu sempre digo que programar e projetar sistemas não é como "levantar muro", é muito mais como "pintar um quadro". Alguém pode até te ensinar como aplicar as cores, mas só você, usando seu bom senso, conhecimento e experiência pode decidir qual cor usar em que momento usar elas, e diria mais, só depois de aplicar as cores algumas vezes você vai pegando o jeito de quais são melhores de usar nos momentos mais adequados.

Quanto a sua dúvida em relação às referências, eu diria, leia todas. A primeira vai te dar uma visão legal de UML, o que é um passo interessante para entender melhor orientação a objetos e também uma forma interessante de aprender como identificar classes, já que o exercício de identificação de casos de uso é um passo importante nesse caminho. As outras referências são bem técnicas, e dou destaque mesmo para o Heads First, apesar de achar uma literatura técnica e massante (leitura, exercício, questõeszinhas... coisa pra quem busca certificação).

Ainda sim recomendo pra você o livro "[The Pragmatic Programmer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020161622X)" por alguns motivos:

1- Não é um livro focado em linguagem e conhecimento de OO não tem ligação direta com a linguagem que voce usa.
2- É um livro que explica situações do dia a dia de um programador, apresenta cenários lúdicos e conceitos de "Broken Window", "Bend or Break" e "Stone Soup"
3- Vejo como literatura obrigatória para qualquer programador que deseja conceber arquiteturas e acumular boas práticas como me parece ser o seu caso.

Quanto ao trecho final da sua pergunta, acredito que tenha respondido uma boa parte dela na introdução inicial e ao longo dessa extensa resposta.

Finalizo aqui deixando duas dicas preciosas pra você:

1. Segurança sobre as decisões técnicas tomadas de forma correta, sendo elas OO ou não, vêm com vivência em tecnologia e milhares de decisões erradas tomadas. Tanto dos outros, quanto suas. Não tenha medo de errar, mas também não erre por não consultar as pessoas a sua volta.
2. Os livros ajudam você a aplicar as cores e são essenciais nessa caminhada, por que eles ajudam voce a construir uma bagagem conceitual que o dia a dia não consegue. Conheco muitos programadores que fazem as coisas no automático e não sabem por que estão fazendo. Esses dias mesmo um dos caras aqui me aplicou um padrão Singleton e não sabia que era um design pattern, ele só sabia que resolvia o problema dele. Em contrapartida, só o dia a dia vai te dar o feeling de como aplicar cada um destes conceitos.

Abraços e Boa Sorte

Comment: Eu conheço o básico do UML, o suficiente para saber que ele não é componente-chave para achar as classes certas, é uma ferramenta apenas. A maioria dos livros da pergunta vai ensinar a usar UML e quando usar, a diferença é se além disso ensinar a achar essas abstrações, esse é o pulo do gato. Dizer que depende de uma combinação de bom senso, conhecimento e principalmente experiência é o que o programador OO padrão faz; e é esse o erro.

Comment: Se OO feito corretamente fosse intuitivo, todo programador razoavelmente experiente teria talento inato em achar os diagramas de classes ótimos de cada situação. E isso não acontece; pensamos que acontece. Achamos uma abstração razoável, que na maioria dos casos atende e talvez não dê maiores problemas; mas cada classe brotou por intuição e não por uma busca mais detalhada da abstração correta. Quando se diz que a maioria dos programadores OO não faz OO corretamente, não se está falando de falta de experiência ou bom senso.

Comment: Você quer uma fórmula pra achar abstrações de classe? Sinto te decepcionar, mas isso não existe. O que você precisa é ler bastante, trabalhar bastante e então encontrar assim o seu "pulo do gato". Quando tiver um livro na prateleira chamado "Fórmula para Achar Abstrações de Classe", me avise

Comment: Pelo contrário, existe sim. _"Livros inteiros foram escritos a respeito de selecionar a abstração dos objetos"._ Não sou eu falando, é o [Allen Wirfs-Brock](http://objology.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/one-of-best-bits-of-programming-advice.html?showComment=1317695961189#c1921540049931674840).

Comment: Sugiro portanto que você vá ler um deles e encontre você mesmo a resposta que você procura. Aliás, quando encontrar, coloque aqui como resposta pra que todos possam tirar proveito do conhecimento.

Comment: Não me entenda mal. Eu não falo que "não sei programar OO" depois de todos esses anos sem uma ferida no meu orgulho. E sei que sua resposta é bem-intencionada. O que estou querendo frisar é que em um diagrama _ideal_ ou _próximo do ideal_ existe uma ciência por trás da escolha das classes que foi "esquecida" pela indústria e da qual as pessoas normalmente não estão a par. Não estou dizendo que é uma panaceia nem que exista um _design ideal único_, mas existem alguns deles para um cenário e isso vai além de ir pela intuição e experiência.

Comment: Até designers de _standard libraries_ de linguagens de programação erram nesse aspecto. É isso que o @bigown quer dizer com fazer OOP correto é complicado e difícil de ensinar.

Comment: Design ideal é o que resolve o seu problema, facilitando refactor quando necessário, atribuindo resposabilidades de forma coesa e coerente, atendendo bem seus requisitos, evitando duplicação de código, promovendo componentização, separação entre as camadas e clareza de código. Se a existe uma abstração específica que seria melhor do que outras, pode até ser que sim, mas isso é tão dependente do problema específico que você está resolvendo, que derivar uma rotina desse processo me parece bem utópico e aberto a interpretações. O que você acharia ideal eu poderia não achar, e vice versa.

Comment: A Rebecca Wirfs-Brock diz que embora cada designer modele de um jeito, _"para um dado problema existem muitas soluções razoáveis, e algumas soluções muito boas"_. Certamente não usar a abstração correta afeta a qualidade do design de alguma maneira. Não sei dizer até que ponto essas "soluções muito boas" melhoram as qualidades do software, porém. O Bertrand Meyer gentilmente me direcionou para o capítulo 5 da 2ª edição do seu livro OOSC no qual ele discute as vantagens do correto uso de OO para a manutenabilidade, extensibilidade e reusabilidade em um nível analítico; é o que tenho no momento.

Comment: @Piovezan a melhor coisa que um programador pode fazer com uma tecnologia é admitir que não entende bem ela a não ser que seja inequívoco que ele entende. Tudo o que você diz nesta página faz muito sentido e mostrando entendimento acima da média. Se todos fizessem o mesmo, os programas seriam bem melhores :) Isto não resolve magicamente nada, mas é um ponto para evitar grandes desastres como vemos todo dia por aí, pela internet, aqui no SOpt. Como é difícil, todo mundo vai responder genericamente, não tem jeito. Qualquer formalização atenderá só pontos específicos. Falta espaço p/ debater tudo

Comment: Com o passar dos anos passei a apreciar mais esta resposta (e ela vai de encontro a um ponto do @utluiz sobre adquirir e aplicar experiência): +1

Comment: Fantástico amigos, sempre feliz em contribuir. Acho que tudo colocado aqui, inclusive a resposta selecionada são ótimos balizadores para outros desenvolvedores